# Why does a aspx/cs project copied locally does not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why does a aspx/cs project copied locally does not work?

I have copied the aspx/cs project right off the server and I put all the code right into my local host area.  I opened the csproj file in visual studio with no problems  I ran it and it did not crash.  But what it does do is this.  It says the Internet Explorer cannot display the page.  Any ideas?

I have done a rebuild and it still fails.  (good news is there is no compile errors)

Answer (score 0):

You need either IIS or IIS Express to run the pages.

Comment: It loads in localhost just fine.  So, are you sure that that is the issue? The browser url is http://localhost:4739/Applications/Graduate/Default.aspx  You mean I have to open IIS and make some sort of arrangement?  When I type localhost in the browser it comes up with that default graphic.  Doesn't that mean that IIS is set up OK?

Comment: @xarzu there might be something wrong with the virtual path settings. i was having issues when tried to run a project that i cloned from github. the virtual path was /Application but changing it to only / worked.

Comment: could you please post the source code of your page, which the Internet Explorer cannot display?

Answer (score -1):

I think I got the answer.

Step through the code.

If you get this far, there is something in the source code that redefines the url to a https instead of http and in debug / local host mode that will mess up the browser display.